# Remove a record in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with entity framework for sometimes now and one thing that really irritates me is the fact that to delete an item we have to find the object and then remove it. so if we have the **PK** of the record we have to get the object and then remove the object.

ex:

```
 Category category = db.Categories.Find(categoryId);
 db.Categories.Remove(category);
 db.SaveChages();
```

In this method we are hitting database twice..!!! 
is there a way to remove the record with just hitting the database once?

**For those none-believers this is the glimpse out come: :)**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're querying twice? Have you seen the actual query behind this? Deferred execution might handles this and optimize.

Comment: yes I'm sure.. I'm using Glimpse.

Comment: Our database isn't being hit twice in my solution.  It seems likely that you're reading glimpse incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// no trip to database
var rec = db.TableName.Local.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == primaryKey);

if (rec == null) throw NotFoundOrWhateverException();

// still no trip to database, if I remember right
db.TableName.Remove(rec);

// trip to database
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: ``SingleOrDefault`` will not fetch from DB are you sure?

Comment: Notice it's applying the `SingleOrDefault()` extension to the _local cache only_.  If you peek at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx) you'll see that this entity reference can be found without a trip to the database.  **ALSO NOTE:** regardless of using .Local the database wouldn't be hit until you called `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: @Daniel Please read my code more closely and you'll see that I did not, _at all_, copy your solution.  I am not hitting the database twice at all.

Comment: You're not hitting the database twice, that is correct, however I don't think this code will work unless the entity is being tracked by EF first!

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't want to get the complete object you can try this way using the primary key property of it:

```
Category category  = new Category () {  Id = categoryId   } ; 
db.Categories.Attach(category);
db.DeleteObject(category);
db.Savechanges();
```

If you are using EF 5 then you can use [EntityFramework.Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) using NUGETand can do like this:

```
db.Categories.Delete(c => c.Id == categoryId);
```

Comment: Good use of anonymous type.  This will work just as well, it's a bit less readable to me but still quite good.

Comment: I'm working with EF6 and there is no such a command as delete

Comment: you have to use Entity Framework Extended Library https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Comment: then you have to use the first option using ``Attach()``

Comment: It throws an exception saying another object already has the PK on attaching.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer turned out to be incorrect. Removed content to keep from confusing others. Kept the post for comment thread.]

Comment: I'm working with EF6 and there is no such a command as delete

Comment: I've removed that from my answer. It appears that it was an extension method that does the very same as I've posted above. Sorry!

Comment: Well then Daniel, I'll retract my answer. It would appear that I've been making multiple calls for many many years of using the Entity Framework.  I guess thanks for showing me Glimpse.